# div below another absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have problem with a div below another div which has "position: absolute".
I need to make **footer** appear UNDER **container** div but now footer is appearing somewhere behind container.
Screen: (div with green background is footer)
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="horni-panel">
    <div class="logo">
        Zhlednuto.cz
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
        Home, about atd.
    </div>

</div>

<!-- Mini pozadi -->
<div class="minipozadi">
    ahoj
</div>

<!-- hlavni obsah -->
<div class="container">


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. x 40
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: Lato-Bold;
    src: url(fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf);
}

body
{
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #a1a8af;
    background-color: #34495e;
}

.horni-panel
{
    border-top: 8px solid #34495e;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height: 77px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.logo
{
    color: #34495e;
    font-family: Lato-Bold;
    font-size: 33px;
}


.minipozadi
{
    height: 282px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(img/bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:1;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
}

.container
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 100;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    margin-top:266px;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-rder-radius: 5px;
}

.footer
{
margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 480px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Do you know that when 'position: absolute' is used, the 'HTML' element for which it is used becomes independent of its parent element & the parent element has no clue about its dimensions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements will be removed from the flow of the document. So the footer moves up because container is not part of that flow. You would need to either use relative positioning on both, or absolute positioning for both and set their specific top and left values.

Alternatively you could set a top margin on footer that makes it drop enough so it is positioned below the container.

You also need to look at your css. There are several redundant properties that are possibly conflicting.

```
body
{
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #a1a8af;
    background-color: #34495e;
}

.horni-panel
{
    border-top: 8px solid #34495e;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    height: 77px;  width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.logo
{
    color: #34495e;
    font-family: Lato-Bold;
    font-size: 33px;
}

.minipozadi
{
    height: 100px;  width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    top: 85px;   left:0;
    z-index:1;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
}

.container
{
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 100;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 120px;
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #fea;
}

.footer
{
    margin-top: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Here in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/animakuz/u4qxofsa/) I removed some of the redundant css and used position:relative on the container div instead of absolute. The margin-top property on the footer needs to be greater than or equal to the top property on the container in order for it to stay below it.

Answer (score 11):

You can insert another blank `div` over your non-absolute `div` and give it height as has your absolute `div`:

```
<div class="absoluteDiv">
    <p>something</p>
</div>
<div class="blankDiv">
    //nothing here
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>Which is covering absolute div</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.absoluteDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.myDiv {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Now we can use `JavaScript` code to get the height of absolute div and give it to our blank div:

```
let absoluteDivHeight = document.getElementByClassName('absoluteDiv')[0].offsetHeight;
let blankDiv = document.getElementByClassName('blankDiv')[0];
blankDiv.style.height = absoluteDivHeight + 5 + "px";
```

Comment: This also works. I just tried this.
Put an empty div below absolute div and make its height to whatever you want
The elements after this empty div will start from that height.
Use ctrl + shift + I to inspect elements margin, padding,etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use a separate wrapper div with 100% height and wrap your container in it that way the wrapper is following the standard flow of the page, and the container can be positioned absolutely within that wrapper, let me know if you need code example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `position:relative`, you can keep both of the div with absolute positioning using JavaScript, as that seems closer to what you are looking for.

What you need here is a function that will set the `top` property of the footer div to the exact value you need it to be.

Here's the code:

```
document.getElementByClassName("container").style.top = (266 + document.getElementByClassName("footer").offsetHeight) + "px";
```

Here's the explenation:

`document.getElementByClassName().style.top` is a [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) method used to change properties through JavaScript, in this case the property is `top`.

The `266` is the amount of pixels you set for property `margin-top` for your container  div.

The `document.getElementByClassName().offsetHeight` function gets the height of an element in pixels (including padding and borders).

Finally, we add "px" to the number, so that the `top`
 property is given in pixels.

This method has its pros and cons:

**Pros:**
 the offset is based on the height of the container div, so it is always positioned directly below the div. You can keep using not only `position:absolute`, but you can use this method also for `position:fixed`.

**Cons:** You must rewrite the code if you add another div that would affect the positioning of the footer. The alignment will not change if you resize the window without reloading the page (you can fix this by running the code every time the window height changes.).

Answer (score 0):

the best answer here isnt that great
had a same problem
just  subordinate your absolute divs into a parent div and position it relative
next, inpect element of the absolute element inside to see its hight, and then enter that height into the parent element.
absolute element, if its not outside the flow (parentless, i.e. attached to body) doesnt go outside the borders of it's parent relative element, so you manually need to put in the dimensions you want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).