# Overlaying a div above another div element using absolute positioning in html

Tags: html, css

I want to position a `div` element under another div element with an absolute position. This is what I have so far:

```css
.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 25%;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: Coral;
}

.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: Aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

(Run code snippet to see what I have)

And I want `.div3` (The blue box) to be below `.div1` (White) and `.div2` (Orange) so you need to scroll the page to see `.div3`. Right now, blue is overlapping orange. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [div below another absolute positioned div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559330/div-below-another-absolute-positioned-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you're asking for:

```css
.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 25%;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: Coral;
}

.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: Aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

I think the misconception came from writing the lengths as percentages aka `width: 100%`. In css the `%` unit means relative to the closest positioned ancestor which in your case is the html itself or the view window. So 100% represents the entire width or height of the window you can see. Setting the `top` property of `div3` to 100% ensures that it will drawn with the top edge along the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I didn't know that 100% meant the whole screen, thanks for that. I also tried making the top property 100%, but forgot the height element, so the div became white. This helped me learn css as I am relatively new to html, css, and javascript. Thank for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

They should have the same parent with the position `relative` (in this case I used `body`). And then you should use `z-index` to specify the stack order of the element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. `.div2` and `.div3` should not have the same `bottom` value. otherwise you can never see the blue one. cause they both stretch to the bottom of the page.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 200vh;
  position: relative;
}
        
.div1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 2;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);;
  z-index: 2;
}

.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
```

Comment: This also helped me! I tried using z-index but didn't modify the body. I have learned something from this answer, but the answer from Joshua Smart helped me more! I would have checked both your and Joshua's answer if I could.